# Azure Blob Storage: Does Microsoft Implement Redundant Backups?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, redundancy

I've searched the web and contacted technical support yet no one seems to be able to give me a straight answer on whether items in Azure Blob Storage are backed up or not.

What I mean is, do I need to create a twin storage account as a "backup" and program copies of all content from one storage to another, or are the contents of a client's Blob Storage automatically redundantly backed up by Microsoft?

*I know with AWS, storage is redundantly backed up via onsite drives as well as across other nodes in the cluster.*

Answer (score 3):

> do I need to create a twin storage account as a "backup" and program
>   copies of all content from one storage to another, or are the contents
>   of a client's Blob Storage automatically redundantly backed up by
>   Microsoft?

Yes, you will need to do backup manually. Azure Storage does not back up the contents of your storage account automatically.

Azure Storage does provide geo-redundant replication (provided you configure the redundancy level for your storage account as GRS or RA-GRS) but that is not back up. Once you delete content from your primary account (location, it will automatically be removed from secondary account (geo-redundant location).

Answer (score 3):

Both AWS (EBS) and Azure(Blob Storage) options provides durability by replicating the data across different data centers. This is for the high availability and durability of the data to provide the guarantee by the cloud provider.

> In order to ensure that your data is durable, Azure Storage has the
>   ability to keep (and manage) multiple copies of your data. This is
>   called replication, or sometimes redundancy. When you set up your
>   storage account, you select a replication type. In most cases, this
>   setting can be modified after the storage account is set up.

For more details refer the replication section in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction).

If you need to capture changes to the storage and allow restore to previous versions (e.g In situations like data corruption or application feature requirements like restore points, backups), you need to take a SnapShot manually. This is common for both AWS and Azure.

For more details on creating a Snapshot of Blob in Azure refer the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/creating-a-snapshot-of-a-blob).

Comment: One quick note: Snapshot of a blob is associated with that blob only. Deleting a blob will delete the snapshot as well. Thus it shouldn't be used for backup purposes.